# Running two apps on port 80 on VPS using Docker

Tags: nginx, docker, django

I have VPS on Digital Ocean and I need to run two separate Django applications using Docker. If I run first app using:

`docker compose up -d` all is fine but when I run second app I get:

> ERROR: for nginx Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming
>   external connectivity on endpoint cockieynginx1
>   (9830ef0c07ed965372d02af22b9263697b6e14822ce4b6717403b78ba68a4e89):
>   Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated

My host system is Ubuntu 16.04. Should I set nginx on my host system with reverse proxy? How to "connect" this with my Docker apps?

Both apps using this Docker settings: https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/tree/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D (see docker-compose.yml and compose folder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a reverse proxy. Bind both Docker containers to different ports (.e.g. 8080 and 8081) and then forward port 80 to them, either based on hostname or directory.

Of course, your reverse proxy could be yet another docker container.

Comment: Whay do you recomend? reverse proxy as another docker container or reverse proxy on host system?

Comment: This is up to you, but I would consider it more logical to have it all together in Docker.